# roblox studio 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near <eof>

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to script some code to create a Folder called Console inside workspace  when someone chatted "Console on" and delete it when someone said "Console off" however when I run it in a public game(because there isn't a chat in roblox studio's test mode) I get the titled error and after reading several posts have come to no answer.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
plr.Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
print("Connected")
if msg == "Console on" then
    console = Instance.new("Folder",workspace)
    console.name = "Console"
    print("Console Made")
elseif 
    msg == "Console off" then
        print("Console Destroyed")
        console:Destroy()
end
end)
```

Comment: You open two functions and one (else)if but there are only two `end`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indent the code more consistently, it will be easier to see where the syntax error is:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
        print("Connected")
        if msg == "Console on" then
            console = Instance.new("Folder",workspace)
            console.name = "Console"
            print("Console Made")
        elseif msg == "Console off" then
            print("Console Destroyed")
            console:Destroy()
        end
    end)
```

Even clearer:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(
    function(plr)
        plr.Chatted:Connect(
            function(msg)
                print("Connected")
                if msg == "Console on" then
                    console = Instance.new("Folder",workspace)
                    console.name = "Console"
                    print("Console Made")
                elseif msg == "Console off" then
                    print("Console Destroyed")
                    console:Destroy()
                end
            end)
```

You need to add another `end)` at the very end to close `game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)`:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(
    function(plr)
        plr.Chatted:Connect(
            function(msg)
                print("Connected")
                if msg == "Console on" then
                    console = Instance.new("Folder",workspace)
                    console.name = "Console"
                    print("Console Made")
                elseif msg == "Console off" then
                    print("Console Destroyed")
                    console:Destroy()
                end
            end)
    end)
```